# How to best locate a directory with a prefix input by the user?

Tags: python

I have a directory that creates a new subfolder each day, each subfolder's name always starts with the date it was created (i.e. MMDDYY). I need to prompt the user for the date of the file they need (something they'd already have) and search for a subfolder that has a matching prefix in the name. The rest of the folder name can be ignored.

If a folder with the correct prefix is found there will be a similar prompt to locate files in the folder that have a name leading with a 5 digit number that the user would also have. Those files just need copied to a new location. I'm just getting stuck on how to locate a subfolder when I only have the prefix to the folder name and same with the file inside that folder once it's found.

For example, I'm looking for a file that generated on 1/10/2019, the file name starts with 42333. The full folder name would be something like 01102019CHA71H2HBMNN. There would be two files that are found, one with a full file name that might be 42333aaabc.xrf and the other would be 42333aaabc with no file extension. These file names could exist in multiple other folders but usually I need them for specific dates.

Comment: Can you add an example of the data and ouput

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [help/on-topic], [ask], and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, including a [mcve] and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Sure I just added an rough example to my post.

Comment: Please read the links that @davedwards included, especially regarding how to write a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you need a algorithm that the input is a prefix (a string).
In Python you can make "membership" tests with strings, for example:

```
>>> string = "A long string"
>>> "long" in string
True
```

Your algorithm would work with something like:

```
"If {prefix as string} in {directory/file name as string}:
do something"
```

But if your question is how to list files inside a directory, you can do this by two libraries:
**os**
**subprocess** (by calling "ls" in Linux or "dir" in Windows)

Or you could use, also the **re** library which is for regular expressions. It's a bit complex but way more flexible.

Good source for debugging RegEx: https://regexr.com/ 
For learning RegEx in Python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Best wishes, pal
For learning

Comment: Thank you! That gives me a starting place!